# NAT on MAC-filtered network

Tags: networking, dhcp, nat, mac-address

My ISP (Hyperion S.A.) provides internet using a UTP cable with MAC filtering. I'm trying to set up a router so that I can connect multiple computers to the network. Most computers would connect through Wifi.

I have a [Linksys WAG160N](http://home.cisco.com/en-apac/products/gateways/WAG160N) which I'm trying to set up. It has a MAC Address Clone feature so MAC filtering isn't an issue (I can also call them up to change the MAC). I've tried configuring it as RFC 1483 Bridged as well as Routed (using the IP I got when connecting from my PC directly).

When connecting a PC to the router it seems to be configured from the ISPs DHCP instead of the router's. Browsing to any page redirects me to a page saying the MAC address is incorrect. The router is configured with DHCP and NAT enabled. There's no Ethernet WAN port, so I'm just plugging the UTP cable into the first port, but I guess any connected computers are detecting the ISPs DHCP since there are effectively two DHCP servers on the network. I would have thought the NAT would prevent that since it's on a different subnet though.

Is there any way to set up this router to make it look like there's one computer from the ISP's perspective but NAT all traffic behind it? It seems like a basic set up, so I'm probably missing something obvious. I'm currently sharing the ethernet connection through Wifi from my laptop using an Adhoc hotspot. If my laptop can do it, surely a router can?

Do I need to install OpenWRT/DD-WRT on the router to support this? DD-WRT says the router isn't supported, but it seems it's only because there's an integrated modem, which I don't care about.

Comment: Sounds like a home based setup, which means it's off-topic on SF.  It'll get moved to SuperUser with a couple more votes.

Comment: I voted for the same and provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is never going to work.

The 4 LAN-ports on this Linksys are just that: LAN-ports connected to an internal 5-port switch.

The 5th port goes to the LAN-side interface of the build-in router.

The WAN-interface of the build-in router connects to the modem.

Even with other firmware this is not going to work. You need to buy a router with a Ethernet WAN interface.

Comment: This is correct.  You need a standard home/soho router where you can plug in the ISP connection to the WAN port.  Then everything should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the inner workings of the modem and router, though it seems obvious now. I guess I'll need to pick up a different router.